# How to create a data model

Tags: ios, swift

I've recently started programming with swift and am currently creating an application, which receives json data from a server. I was wondering about the best way to create the data model. First I tried creating a class and `if let`ing all of the properties, but I found it to be too cumbersome (I have objects with 10-12 proeprties):

```
class Favourite {

    var mArtikelText: String = ""
    var mRid: String = ""

    init(object: [String: AnyObject]) throws {
        if let text = object["text"] as? String {
            self.mArtikelText = text
        }
        if let id = object["id"] as? String {
            self.mRid = id
        }
    }
}
```

Then I read about the new `guard` keyword and decided to try with it:

```
enum JSONResponseError: ErrorType {
    case NilResponseValue
}

class Favourite {

    var mArtikelText: String
    var mRid: String

    init(object: [String: AnyObject]) throws {
        guard let text = object["text"] as? String else {
            self.mArtikelText = ""
            throw JSONResponseError.NilResponseValue
        }
        guard let rid = object["id"] as? String else {
            self.mRid = ""
            throw JSONResponseError
        }
        self.mArtikelText = text
        self.mRid = rid
    }
}
```

But I get `All stored properties of a class instance must be initialized before throwing from an initializer`. I guess I could silence the error if I initialize the properties, when I declare them, as I did in the first example, but (correct me if I'm wrong) I thought the `guard` is used to avoid exactly this approach.

Then I tried `guarding` all the properties at once:

```
class Favourite {

    var mArtikelText: String 
    var mRid: String

    init(object: [String: AnyObject]) throws {

        guard case let (text as String, rid as String) = (object["text"], object["id"]) else {
            self.mArtikelText = ""
            self.mRid = ""
            throw JSONResponseError.NilResponseValue
        }
        self.mArtikelText = text
        self.mRid = rid
    }
}
```

But I don't like this approach, because I want to leave only the faulty values and work with the rest (sometimes I receive `nil` values, that I won't be using anyway, so there is no point in throwing the whole answer away).

So, my question is, what is the best way to create a reliable model class from a json dictionary?

Comment: Initializing `String` variables with an empty string as in your first example is fine, you get a default value in any case and it does not interfere the `guard` expressions since the empty value will be overwritten on success.

Comment: Please check out some third party libraries that greatly simplify the task. SwiftyJSON is good, give it a try.

Comment: As @TheAppMentor said, try use some third-party libs. Or make your instance vars optional (with `!` or `?` suffix).